# Cannot deploy Spring Boot application

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, cloudcontrol

I'm currently evaluating CloudControl as platform provider for my Java based applications.

I created a very simple Spring Boot (https://github.com/mhmpl/gradle-example-app) app with Gradle but I'm unable to deploy the app.

There are no errors in the `Error` log which could give me some information. However, this is the output of the `Deploy` log:

```
8/3/14 12:53 PM lxc-1272 INFO Container did not come up within 120 seconds.
8/3/14 12:53 PM lxc-1250 INFO Waiting for the container to be reachable...
8/3/14 12:53 PM lxc-1272 INFO Waiting for the container to be reachable...
8/3/14 12:52 PM lxc-1250 INFO Waiting for the container to be reachable...
8/3/14 12:52 PM lxc-1272 INFO Waiting for the container to be reachable...
8/3/14 12:52 PM lxc-1250 INFO Waiting for the container to be reachable...
8/3/14 12:52 PM lxc-1272 INFO Waiting for the container to be reachable...
8/3/14 12:51 PM lxc-1250 INFO Deploying ...
```

Finally, the app is not deployed and I cannot see an error which I've potentially made. I already tried to set the memory to 1024MB and added a second container, but that did not change anything at all.

Comment: I compared my project to `https://github.com/Agraphie/springboot-gradle-cctrl-example` and I found and the other project seems to initialize the `dispatcherServlet` after the Tomcat was started.

Comment: Are you binding to the correct port? It's defined in the PORT environment variable.

Comment: @StefanFriesel: I thought I did, but not properly. Thank you! I've updated it here (https://github.com/mhmpl/hellocctrl/blob/master/src/main/java/hellocctrl/Application.java) and now it works :-)

Comment: Nice, I'll move the comment to an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the webserver to the correct port, which is defined in the PORT environment variable.